# 98 Camry Oil Pump: When does oil need to be replaced?

Tags: oil, camry, pump

I removed a 98 Camry 2.2L 4-cyl oil pump to change the timing belt & seals:

[image]

There seems to be wear in the red annotated area. The wear is only on that half section, not under the lobe with the triangle on it.  You can feel the wear with your finger nail.  The other side of the housing on the vehicle has a grove worn in as well.  The shaft in the pump the sprocket bolts to has no play.  How does one know if it is time to change the pump?  Pump has 100K miles

Comment: Is there any play on the shaft?

Comment: No play on the shaft.

Comment: The pump should last the life of the engine under normal operating conditions and regular maintenance.